# In Swift, is it possible to convert a string to an enum?

Tags: swift, enums

If I have an enum with the cases a,b,c,d is it possible for me to cast the string "a" as the enum?

Comment: These 'casts' are called literal conversions.

Answer (score 185):

Sure. Enums can have a raw value. To quote the docs:

> Raw values can be strings, characters, or any of the integer or
> floating-point number types
>
> — Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l,

So you can use code like this:

```
enum StringEnum: String 
{
    case one   = "value one"
    case two   = "value two"
    case three = "value three"
}

let anEnum = StringEnum(rawValue: "value one")!

print("anEnum = \"\(anEnum.rawValue)\"")
```

Note: You don't need to write = "one" etc. after each case. The default string values are the same as the case names so calling `.rawValue` will just return a string

### EDIT

If you need the string value to contain things like spaces that are not valid as part of a case value then you need to explicitly set the string. So,

```
enum StringEnum: String 
{
  case one
  case two
  case three
}

let anEnum = StringEnum.one
print("anEnum = \"\(anEnum)\"")
```

gives

> anEnum = "one"

But if you want `case` `one` to display "value one" you will need to provide the string values:

```
enum StringEnum: String 
{
  case one   = "value one"
  case two   = "value two"
  case three = "value three"
}
```

Comment: The raw value must be literal convertible. You can't use just any `Hashable` type.

Comment: Ok... I quoted the Apple docs, which lists the types of values that can be used as enum raw values. Strings, the OP's question, are one of the supported types.

Comment: Hmm, imagine `case one = "uno"`. Now, how to parse `"one"` to enum value? (can't use raws, as they're used for localisation)

Comment: Maybe you could initialize the raw String upon initialization depending on the localization ... or simply have different enum each for a different localization. In any case the whole purpose of having an enum is to abstract away the underlying raw i.e. the localization. A good code design would not be passing "uno" as parameter anywhere but relying on  StringEnum.one

Comment: @user2763173, you should either accept one of the answers or explain how the answers given don't answer your question. Failure to accept a good answer is considered bad form on SO.

Comment: You don't need to write `= "one"` etc. after each case. The default string values are the same as the case names.

Comment: @tuple_cat, really? Cool. In what version of Swift is this supported?

Comment: I can't find any documentation for Swift <2.2 but it's in 2.2...3.0, at least: [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID535).

Comment: @emlai, did your handle (SO username) used to be "tuple_cat"? If so, SO goes back and changes our usernames even in old posts, which I find interesting.)

Comment: Yeah. Shame it doesn't update the username in @replies in comments.

Answer (score 48):

In Swift 4.2, the CaseIterable protocol can be used for an enum with rawValues, but the string should match against the enum case labels:

```
enum MyCode : String, CaseIterable {

    case one   = "uno"
    case two   = "dos"
    case three = "tres"

    static func withLabel(_ label: String) -> MyCode? {
        return self.allCases.first{ "\($0)" == label }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
print(MyCode.withLabel("one")) // Optional(MyCode.one)
print(MyCode(rawValue: "uno"))  // Optional(MyCode.one)
```

Comment: This is a great answer! It actually addresses the question.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually works as the OP asked, which was about *case names* not raw values.  Good answer!

Comment: While this works, its a very silly thing to do. Please dont base functionality on names of cases in code.

Comment: What else is he supposed to do? What if he's writing an enum to a database and then needs to cast it back?

Answer (score 45):

All you need is:

```
enum Foo: String {
   case a, b, c, d
}

let a = Foo(rawValue: "a")
assert(a == Foo.a)

let  = Foo(rawValue: "")
assert( == nil)
```

Comment: This isn't technically the right answer as this checks the raw value.  In the example here as given, there is no raw value specified, so it's implicitly matched to the case name, but if you have an enum with a raw value, this breaks.

Answer (score 21):

In case with an enum with Int type you can do it so:

```
enum MenuItem: Int {
    case One = 0, Two, Three, Four, Five //... as much as needs

    static func enumFromString(string:String) -> MenuItem? {
        var i = 0
        while let item = MenuItem(rawValue: i) {
            if String(item) == string { return item }
            i += 1
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

And use:

```
let string = "Two"
if let item = MenuItem.enumFromString(string) {
    //in this case item = 1 
    //your code
}
```

Comment: It's crazy that you can't just use similar functionality builtin into the language. I can imagine you store values in JSON for example by the enum name, and then on parsing need to convert them back. Writing a `enumFromString` method for each enum you use seems crazy.

Comment: @Peterdk, please suggest the best possible alternative. Igor solution actually just worked for me.

Comment: @Hemang It works ok, alright, but a better solution would be Swift support for automatically doing this. It's crazy to do this manually for each enum. But yes, this works.

Comment: @Peterdk, can you please add a separate answer for the same? It would surely help everyone out here.

Comment: Its not crazy that Swift does not support it natively. The crazy thing is that the functionality rely on the name of a type. When the value changes, you will have to refactor and rename all usages. This is not the correct way to solve this.

Answer (score 9):

Riffing on djruss70's answer to create highly generalized solution:

```
extension CaseIterable {
    static func from(string: String) -> Self? {
        return Self.allCases.first { string == "\($0)" }
    }
    func toString() -> String { "\(self)" }
}
```

Usage:

```
enum Chassis: CaseIterable {
    case pieridae, oovidae
}

let chassis: Chassis = Chassis.from(string: "oovidae")!
let string: String = chassis.toString()
```

Note: this will unfortunately not work if the enum is declared @objc.  As far as I know as of Swift 5.3 there is no way to get this to work with @objc enum's except brute force solutions (a switch statement).

If someone happens to know of a way to make this work for @objc enums, I'd be very interested in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4.2:

```
public enum PaymentPlatform: String, CaseIterable {
    case visa = "Visa card"
    case masterCard = "Master card"
    case cod = "Cod"

    var nameEnum: String {
        return Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first?.label ?? String(describing: self)
    }

    func byName(name: String) -> PaymentPlatform {
        return PaymentPlatform.allCases.first(where: {$0.nameEnum.elementsEqual(name)}) ?? .cod
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Extending Duncan C's answer

```
extension StringEnum: StringLiteralConvertible {

    init(stringLiteral value: String){
        self.init(rawValue: value)!
    }

    init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(stringLiteral: value)
    }

    init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(stringLiteral: value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Int enum and their String representation, I declare enum as follows:

```
enum OrderState: Int16, CustomStringConvertible {

    case waiting = 1
    case inKitchen = 2
    case ready = 3

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .waiting:
            return "Waiting"
        case .inKitchen:
            return "InKitchen"
        case .ready:
            return "Ready"
        }
    }

    static func initialize(stringValue: String)-> OrderState? {
        switch stringValue {
        case OrderState.waiting.description:
            return OrderState.waiting
        case OrderState.inKitchen.description:
            return OrderState.inKitchen
        case OrderState.ready.description:
            return OrderState.ready

        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
order.orderState = OrderState.waiting.rawValue

let orderState = OrderState.init(rawValue: order.orderState)
let orderStateStr = orderState?.description ?? ""
print("orderStateStr = \(orderStateStr)")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the other answers make this way more complicated then it needs to be. Here is a quick and concise example.

```
enum Gender: String {
    case male, female, unspecified
}
```

Simple enum, note that I added ": String" to the enum itself to declare the type as string.

Now all you have to do is:

```
let example: Gender = Gender(rawValue: "male")
```

And thats it, 'example' is now an enum of type Gender with the value of .male

There is literally nothing else you need to do in Swift 4+.

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
public enum Currency: CaseIterable, Codable {
    case AFN = 971 // Afghani (minor=2)
    case DZD = 012 // Algerian Dinar (minor=2)

...

    private static var cachedLookup: [String: Currency] = [:]
    
    init?(string: String) {
        if Self.cachedLookup.isEmpty {
            Self.cachedLookup = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: Self.allCases.map { ("\($0)", $0) })
        }
        
        if let currency = Self.cachedLookup[string] {
            self = currency
            return
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```