# How can I create an array of enum values from an array of Strings

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, enums

I have an array of strings that a returned from an API. These strings are a list of products available.

I would like to use an enum in my app to represent this data. I am unsure if this is possible however.

```
enum Products: String {
    case music
    case cars
    case sport
}
```

An example array I receive could be `["music", "cars"]`

This is part of a struct that would be

```
struct CustomerState: Codable {
    var products = [Product]()
}
```

I was imaging I could map of the array and perhaps compare raw values, however I cannot work out how to do this or if this is the correct / possible approach.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009788/in-swift-is-it-possible-to-convert-a-string-to-an-enum) out

Comment: Simply specifing that `Products` conforms to `Codable` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve it by *mapping* the current array of strings to an array of enum cases based on their rawValues:

```
let array = ["music", "cars", "tomato"]
let arrayEnum = array.map { Products(rawValue: $0) }
```

At this point, keep in mind that `arrayEnum` is `[Products?]` containing 3 elements  because mapping "tomato" string gives `nil`. What you could do for getting rid of nils is to use the `compactMap`:

```
let array = ["music", "cars", "tomato"]

let arrayEnum = array.compactMap { Products(rawValue: $0) }
print(arrayEnum)
```

Now `arrayEnum` contains only two elements without the `nil` one.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you have json like this

```
let data = Data("""
{
"products" : [ "music", "cars" ]
}
""".utf8)
```

then you can just implement `Codable` to your enum

```
struct CustomerState: Codable {
    var products = [Products]()
}

enum Products: String, Codable {
    case music
    case cars
    case sport
}
```

and then you can decode `Data`

```
do {
    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(CustomerState.self, from: data)
    //print(decoded.products[0])
} catch { print(error) }
```

---

Alternatively, if json always doesn't have to contains just declared enum cases, you can create custom initializer with decoder which decodes string array and then tries to create enum values from these strings. If case for this raw value doesn't exist, it isn't appended

```
struct CustomerState: Decodable {

    var products = [Products]()

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case products
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let products = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .products)
        self.products = products.compactMap { Products(rawValue: $0) }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you get an unexpected value in your API response, entire decoding will fail.

Comment: As a confirmation to @Losiowaty's comment, the array in the json is `["music", "cheese"]` you will get an error of "Cannot initialize Products from invalid String value cheese".